# What are the pitfalls of putting some of your data model and/or functions on Angular's $rootScope?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Necessitating the injection of a service in a controller in order to have access to data and/or functions can be thought of as both a pro and a con.

*What I'm trying to determine is what are the **objective "pitfalls"** of utilizing the `$rootScope` for often used bits of data and or functions?*

(**Note**: I'm not trying to start a religious war here, but instead be able to make well informed decisions.)

Comment: In my experience injecting $rootScope everywhere leads me to use root scope for too much out of convenience. This snowballs and before you know it everything knows about everything else and conflicts arise because of global state. I just say never go down that path. Take some time to organize data and functionality into Factories/Services/Values instead.

Answer (score 2):

It's like polluting of global namespace in plain JavaScript. You are polluting your application's global space. It's never good to do that (in any of the languages).

But there are some reasonable usages of rootScope...Angular says:

> Of course, global state sucks and you should use $rootScope sparingly, like you would (hopefully) use with global variables in any language. In particular, don't use it for code, only data. If you're tempted to put a function on $rootScope, it's almost always better to put it in a service that can be injected where it's needed, and more easily tested.